# FPDF / PHP: Footer page is display at the bottom of the next page (Blank page)

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

Currently, I create a system that can generate PDF. Data at the PDF is from MySQL Database. For now, I display the data like this

First page: Only display one data.

Second page on words: will display data (maximum 3 data per page)

To be more clear,  example I have 6 data, it will display like this:

First page = 1 data display

Second Page = 3 data display

Third page 2 data display

Now, I want to add the footer. The footer will display at the end of the page (at the bottom). I already created the footer.

If the LAST PAGE contain 1 or 2 data, the footer will display at the bottom of that page. BUT... if The LAST PAGE contain 3 data, the footer will display at bottom of next page (blank page). I dont know what is the problem. Can anyone help?

Below is my code

```
  $user3 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid LEFT JOIN ot_team ON ot_team.team_id = ot_users.team_id 
  WHERE ot_team.team_id = '".$_GET['team']."' AND report_date BETWEEN '".$_GET["from"]."' AND '".$_GET["to"]."' ORDER BY ot_report.report_date DESC");
      $count = 0;
      while ($row = $user3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

          $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
          $pdf->Cell(20,7,'Date:',1,0);
          $pdf->Cell(67,7,date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['report_date'])),1,0);
          $pdf->Cell(20,7,'Time:',1,0);
          $pdf->Cell(34,7,"From: ".date('H:i',strtotime($row['ot_start'])),1,0);
          $pdf->Cell(33,7,"To: ".date('H:i',strtotime($row['ot_end'])),1,1); 
          $pdf->Cell(87,7,'Before',1,0,'C');
          $pdf->Cell(87,7,'After',1,1, 'C');

          $logo = file_get_contents('../../images/faces/noimage.png');

          if(!isset($row['photo_before']) || empty($row['photo_before'])) {
            $pdf->Cell(87, 57, $pdf->MemImage($logo, $pdf->GetX()+20, $pdf->GetY()+5, 47,47,), 1, 0, 'C');
          }else{ 
            $pdf->Cell(87, 57, $pdf->MemImage(base64_decode($row['photo_before']), $pdf->GetX()+21, $pdf->GetY()+2, 45,53,), 1, 0, 'C');
          }

          if(!isset($row['photo_after']) || empty($row['photo_after'])) {
            $pdf->Cell(87, 57, $pdf->MemImage($logo, $pdf->GetX()+20, $pdf->GetY()+5, 47,47,), 1, 1, 'C');
          }else{ 
            $pdf->Cell(87, 57, $pdf->MemImage(base64_decode($row['photo_after']), $pdf->GetX()+21, $pdf->GetY()+2, 45,53,), 1, 1, 'C');
          }

          if ($row['time_photo_before'] == null){
            $pdf->Cell(87,7,'-',1,0, 'C');
          }else{
            $pdf->Cell(87,7,$row['time_photo_before'],1,0, 'C');
          }

          if ($row['time_photo_after'] == null){
            $pdf->Cell(87,7,'-',1,1, 'C');
          }else{
            $pdf->Cell(87,7,$row['time_photo_after'],1,1, 'C');
          }

          if ((($count - 3) % 3) === 0) {


            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->Cell(60,7,'',0,1,"C");

          }

        $count++;

      }

      $pdf->Footer($pdf->SetY(-48));

      $pdf->Footer($pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9));
      $pdf->Footer($pdf->Cell(58,9,'Prepared by,',0,0,"C"));
      $pdf->Footer($pdf->Cell(58,9,'Verified by,',0,0,"C"));
      $pdf->Footer($pdf->Cell(58,9,'Approved by,',0,1,"C"));

  $pdf->Output();

  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend the FPDF class and modify the default footer. Any time a new page is started the contents of the footer method will be called which should get you the desired result.

```
class PDF extends FPDF {
    function Footer() {
      $this->SetY(-48));
      $this->SetFont('Arial','B',9));
      $this->Cell(58,9,'Prepared by,',0,0,"C"));
      $this->Cell(58,9,'Verified by,',0,0,"C"));
      $this->Cell(58,9,'Approved by,',0,1,"C"));
    }  // end of the Footer function
}  // end of the PDF class
```

Comment: Can't answer that since you didn't include all of your code in your original question. Someplace you are likely creating an instance of FPDF as shown in my answer and that object is named `$pdf` based on your code. Once you have created the footer you no longer need those lines in the code you posted.